# Unable to start User Profile Synchronization service

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

I am trying to configure User Profile Synchronization service in SP 2013 server but unable to start the relevant service since it is showing NT Authority\Network Service account, although SharePoint Administrator service, Timer service and app pool are running in context of SP Farm admin account.

How to change this account here? Please see screenshot below. Thanks in advance.
[image: User Profile Synch service login account]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like **NT Authority\Network Service** account is your farm admin account.

1st you have to change your farm admin account to domain account then you will be able to run the UPA service. You cant run this under nt auth account as  there is an explicit check to validate that the UPSS is running under the context of this account during provisioning.

[Read this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4963df7-6bab-4751-ae45-38a04764313e/sharepoint-2010-change-user-profile-service-account-from-nt-authoritynetwork-service-to-my-service?forum=sharepointadminprevious)  and [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/983061)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Active Directory, under Active Directory Users and Computers and give the farm account special permission, in this case it seems Network Service Account which user synchronization service is using.

- Go to domain, right click and select delegate control
- Click next and your UPSS account, click next
- Create custom task and click next, keep the default scope of the
  task, click next
- Select the permission General and select replicating Directory
  Changes,click next and finished.

After that add the account under local Security Policy to allow log on using log on locally option. Also you need to add UPSS account to local machine as admin.
Reboot your server.

- Now go to UPSS and enter your password and confirm password. It will
  get started (wait for 5 mins)

Also you have to configure Synchronization connection and setting.